# Convert const Byte* to std::string c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can i convert const Byte* to std::string.I tried the following

```
std::string sTemp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ByteBuffer));
```

Where ByteBuffer is const Byte*.Not got the value of ByteBuffer in sTemp using the above code
Please help

Thanks,

Comment: What is `Byte`? What do you mean by "not got the value"?

Answer (score 2):

If `ByteBuffer` contains a NUL-terminated string, then the code should work fine.

If it doesn't, you need to supply its length as the second parameter to the [`string` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

The above assumes that `Byte` is what I think it is, and that `ByteBuffer` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such data type as 'Byte' in C++. I assume it's a 8-bit data store if at all it exists, in which case your code is correct. Make sure there's a null character - '\0' in the buffer.

Comment: BYTE, on the other hand, is defined by Windows.

Comment: Another thing to note is that BYTE will likely be an `unsigned char`.